Maui - How read objectbox db
I currently have an app that was built in native Android and uses objectbox as db. This app will be updated under a development made in Maui .net 8. So when an old user of the native Android app updates to the new Maui app, I need to read the data.mdb, and migrate the data to my new data.db (sqlite). I can't find any Maui library that supports objectbox, in order to read the db. How or what should I do?

if they have a .NET library, use that.  If not, create a wrapper for their native Android library.

I recommend to get your users to migrate from objectbox to db in either (1) the native Android app, (2) through a conversion tool you run on a desktop machine, (3) you build and host a REST endpoint which you can call from MAUI
